# How to connect a source filter to an encoder DMO?

Tags: winapi, video, directshow, wmv, dmo

I have a DirectShow app for generating silent videos, whose filter graph is

```
my video frame generator -> selectable video compressor -> AVI mux -> file writer
```

or just

```
my video frame generator -> AVI mux -> file writer
```

This mostly works as expected, unless the selected compressor is a DMO, in which case the pFilterGraph->Connect() call from source to compressor fails - typically with VFW_E_TYPE_NOT_ACCEPTED or VFW_E_CANNOT_CONNECT.  I would like to make DMOs work too.  I found a deprecated sample (AVIEncoderDShow) that I was able to tweak to compress an input AVI file with the WMV9 DMO, which seemed promising on this score.  Its filter graph is

```
pFilterGraph->AddSourceFilter(AVI file) -> AVI splitter -> DMO wrapper for WMV -> AVI mux -> file writer
```

so I thought I could just swap out the source filter for my filter (or the bouncing ball DirectShow sample that it's based on).  Trying that just gives the same connection failures though.  The source I'm supplying is 32 bit RGB, which WMV9 should accept.  What might it be stumbling on?

EDIT:
The details of my preferred media type are:

```
majortype: MEDIATYPE_Video
subtype: MEDIASUBTYPE_RGB32
bFixedSizeSamples: 1
bTemporalCompression: 0
lSampleSize: 3145728
formattype: CLSID_KsDataTypeHandlerVideo
pUnk: NULL
cbFormat: 1128
pbFormat: 0x12ce4bf0
```

and the exact point of failure with VFW_E_TYPE_NOT_ACCEPTED is

```
hr = pReceivePin->ReceiveConnection((IPin *)this, pmt);
CBasePin::AttemptConnection(IPin * pReceivePin, const CMediaType * pmt) Line 1796   C++
CBasePin::AgreeMediaType(IPin * pReceivePin, const CMediaType * pmt) Line 1939  C++
CBasePin::Connect(IPin * pReceivePin, const _AMMediaType * pmt) Line 1728   C++
CFilterGraph::ConnectDirectInternal(struct IPin *,struct IPin *,struct _AMMediaType const *)    Unknown
CFilterGraph::ConnectDirect(struct IPin *,struct IPin *,struct _AMMediaType const *)    Unknown
ConnectFilters(IBaseFilter * pUpstream, IBaseFilter * pDownstream, IGraphBuilder * pGraph, _AMMediaType * pmt) Line 332 C++
```

My media type's pbFormat is set up as a VIDEOINFO, which seems to have the same structure as a VIDEOINFOHEADER but with additional data tacked on the end of it.  It looks like this:

```
rcSource    {LT(0, 0) RB(0, 0)  [0 x 0]}    tagRECT
rcTarget    {LT(0, 0) RB(0, 0)  [0 x 0]}    tagRECT
dwBitRate   0   unsigned long
dwBitErrorRate  0   unsigned long
AvgTimePerFrame 0   __int64
bmiHeader   {biSize=40 biWidth=1024 biHeight=768 ...}   tagBITMAPINFOHEADER
    biSize  40  unsigned long
    biWidth 1024    long
    biHeight    768 long
    biPlanes    1   unsigned short
    biBitCount  32  unsigned short
    biCompression   0   unsigned long
    biSizeImage 3145728 unsigned long
    biXPelsPerMeter 0   long
    biYPelsPerMeter 0   long
    biClrUsed   0   unsigned long
    biClrImportant  0   unsigned long
bmiColors   0x0d381c60 {{rgbBlue=0 '\0' rgbGreen=0 '\0' rgbRed=0 '\0' ...}, {rgbBlue=0 '\0' rgbGreen=0 '\0' rgbRed=...}, ...}   tagRGBQUAD[256]
dwBitMasks  0x0d381c60 {0, 0, 0}    unsigned long[3]
    [0] 0   unsigned long
    [1] 0   unsigned long
    [2] 0   unsigned long
TrueColorInfo   {dwBitMasks=0x0d381c60 {0, 0, 0} bmiColors=0x0d381c6c {{rgbBlue=0 '\0' rgbGreen=0 '\0' rgbRed=0 '\0' ...}, ...} }
```

Comment: `VFW_E_TYPE_NOT_ACCEPTED` means that type is incompatible. DMO will only accept some media types and your source is also capable to provide data of specific media type. You will succeed in connecting if there is a match... Perhaps you should post more details of what exactly you have (media type on source).

Comment: `CLSID_KsDataTypeHandlerVideo` is `FORMAT_VideoInfo`? What's in the `VIDEOINFOHEADER`. I would suppose WMV encoder accepts 32-bit RGB.

Comment: @RomanR.: Yes, it's the same value as FORMAT_VideoInfo.  I've added the info to the main question.

Comment: I don't think you need data additional to `VIDEOINFOHEADER` (making cbFormat as big as 1128), but it's unlikely to be a problem. What could really make connection fail is zero `AvgTimePerFrame`, I'd try a non-zero value there. I just quick checked - yes, I can connect my 32-bit RGB source to Wrapped WMV9 DMO.

Comment: @RomanR. : Setting AvgTimePerFrame does indeed solve the problem!  Thanks very much!  If you want to add that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some filters, especially multiplexers and sometimes encoders, require that you specify frame rate of the video stream. And otherwise the media types are rejected with generic error code, without a mention that frame rate is the cause.

WMV9 Encoder DMO does accept 32-bit RGB on the input, so you should try it out with a positive `AvgTimePerFrame` value in `VIDEOINFOHEADER` structure of the media type:

[image]